# Войдите во вход, пожалуйста

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Посмотрел я тут случайно на очередь проверок без авторизации на сайте и увидел такое:

> [image: проверка]

Для одних очередей просят "войти", для других "выполнить вход", иногда даже добавляют "пожалуйста". Надо бы навести порядок.

Все оригинальные строки при этом начинаются так:

> Please log in to review

Голосуйте за предложенные варианты, или предлагайте свои. Пусть победит сильнейший :)

Comment: Будьте так любезны, милейший человек, произведите личностную идентификацию, верификацию и авторизацию

Comment: @АлексейШиманский как вариант ответа не желаете оформить? :)

Comment: О, зебра :) Ну почти зебра)))

Comment: @Qwertiy какая ещё зебра? :)

Comment: @alexolut, ну чередуются они, кроме запоздалых ответов.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Использовать вариант:

> Пожалуйста, войдите

Answer (score -1):

Использовать вариант:

> Выполните вход